# Using Salesforce dashboard in salesforce MOBILE sdk based app or may be some other app out side salesforce context

Tags: lightning-web-components, dashboard, mobilesdk, custom-reports, einstein-analytics-dashboards

I want to render the salesforce based dashboards in mobile app which is based on SFSDK only. What will be the best way to do it?

Currently i am making the call to get the dashboard data and then using the CHRTS library to draw the dashboard data.

Is there any better idea, which can reduce the amount of work?

May be creating the LWC components which contains these dashboards and then render them in mobile app or any where else?

Thanks,
Manjeet

Comment: `Is there any better idea, which can reduce the amount of work?` -> if you mean dev work, then just create a webview and redirect users to your dashboard. Inject some javascript to hide all menus etc. and you can have a full screen experience.

If you want a nicer experience, use reports api to pull out data and build native charts.